# __unsafe_unretained leading to message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I am using a block to perform a network related task

When the block completes in my `UITableViewController`, I want to reload the tableviewcontroller

```
__unsafe_unretained UITableView *unretTableView = self.tableview;

[myRequest postWithCompletion:(bool finished) {
    [unretTableView reloadData];
}];
```

This is fine, except that if I leave (`deallocate`) the `UITableViewController` before the request has finished I seem to be pointing to a deallocated object (`unretTableView`) *message sent to deallocated instance* even though in the `[UITableViewController dealloc]` method (which is being called) I set `self.tableview = nil;`

Additional details:

- Can't use `__weak`, I am targeting iOS 4.3 and above
- In the `UITableViewController`'s `dealloc` method, i set `self.tableview = nil`
- I do not want to cancel the network request when you leave the page, I want it to keep running.
- edit: I do not want to retain self.tableview in the block either

thanks!

Comment: A bunch of options: 1. Shift to delegate pattern where you have some object doing the updating and the tableview controller sets its delegate to point to the tableview controller. 2. Use a NSOperation for the background update, and have the tableview controller cancel it if the controller is going away and no longer needs the data. Have operation check to make sure it's not cancelled before telling the tableview to reload. 3. Use notifications, so the notification center will tell tableview when it needs to be reloaded.

Comment: What lib are you using for network request? Surely it would be best to cancel the request otherwise you are pointlessly using resources

Comment: thanks @Rob While delegate pattern would help, I'm in the same situation if I am using blocks as the request can be one of many post requests, queued up. I can iterate through on dealloc and set all the blocks to nil (vs. set all the delegates to nil) just wondering if there is a cleaner way to do this.
As for option 2 i suppose it would be the same thing, iterating through and canceling the operations. I've considered notifications but would prefer to keep blocks (if I can have my cake and eat it too)

Answer (score 1):

Given your comments, I might be inclined to pursue a [`NSOperationQueue`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html). This way you can

1. Create a background `NSOperationQueue`;
2. If your download permits a certain reasonable number of simultaneous downloads, you can set [`maxOperationCount`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSOperationQueue/setMaxConcurrentOperationCount%3a) (or if you want serial, set this to 1).
3. As you initiate your background jobs, you can create `NSOperation` objects, or just submit directly to the `NSOperationQueue` with blocks via [`addOperationWithBlock`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSOperationQueue/addOperationWithBlock%3a). You might need to do the former if you want to enjoy the ability to check the `isCancelled` flag.
4. Each operation can check to see if it's cancelled before trying to update the view controller.
5. When the view controller is dismissed, it can perform a simple [`cancelAllOperations`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSOperationQueue/cancelAllOperations) to cancel everything that is queued up.

Here's a random example:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    self.queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 4;

    // let's add 100 operations to our queue

    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        NSBlockOperation *operation = [[NSBlockOperation alloc] init];
        __unsafe_unretained NSBlockOperation *weakOperation = operation; // it seems vaguely disturbing to do this with __unsafe_unretained, but given that the operation queue is taking care of this for us, I believe it's ok
        [operation addExecutionBlock:^{

            NSLog(@"Beginning operation %d", i);

            sleep(10);

            if ([weakOperation isCancelled])
                NSLog(@"Operation cancelled %d", i);
            else
            {
                // go ahead and update UI if you want
                NSLog(@"Finished operation %d", i);
            }
        }];

        [self.queue addOperation:operation];
    }
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    [self.queue cancelAllOperations];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you set the property to later has no bearing on what the variable captured by the block is set to. If you want to access the property, you need to access the property: self.foo, rather than foo.

Note that you still have to be careful in that case, since capturing self in the block will result in self being retained, which could cause a retain cycle.

(edit)
And this still won't be safe if you're updating the property from another thread. You'll need a serialization construct of some form to make that safe (NSLock, NSOperationQueue, dispatch_queue_t, etc...). I'm assuming this isn't threaded, but just in case it is, that's important.

Comment: Thanks, Edited my question to include that I'd like to avoid capturing self strongly as a lengthy timeout would leave my TableViewController alive a lot longer than I'd like

Comment: No matter if he uses self.foo or foo, the table view controller is already deallocated so no variable is available.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri: That is not correct. Using `self.foo` in the block *retains* `self`, so the table view controller will not be deallocated before the block has run.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
__block __unsafe_unretained UITableView *unretTableView = self.tableview;
```

**EDIT**

I don't know what framework you use to post the request.But when you post the request with *[myRequest postWithCompletion: yourBlock]*, I suppose that there is also a way to change the completion block, something like *myRequest.completion=nil*.

Comment: __block would not cause the variable to be set to nil. There is exactly one way to have a variable automatically set to nil when it's deallocated, and that is 'weak'.

Comment: I know it, I thought that unretTableView was invalid because he exited from the method's stack.

Comment: @Catfish_Man not exactly one way check [MAZeroingWeakRef](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-07-16-zeroing-weak-references-in-objective-c.html)

Comment: MAZeroingWeakRef is an implementation of weak, I would say, but yes.

Answer (score -2):

Insert a sanity check.

```
__weak UITableView *table = unretTableView;
if (table) [unretTableView reloadData];
```

Comment: Checking for nil will not help in this case. The entire point of __unsafe_unretained is that it doesn't get set to nil when the object goes away.

Comment: Yes. That is the only difference between __weak and __unsafe_unretained.